# Como adicionar googleMap programaticamente em um RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout

Eu já tenho todas as configurações externas realizadas, mas minha dúvida é como adicionar googleMap programaticamente em um RelativeLayout?

Aqui está meu RelativeLayout

```
public class Page extends RelativeLayout {

private Context context;

public Page(Context context) {
  super(context);
  this.context = context;
  this.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

 // Eu preciso gerar o  googleMap aqui

  }
}
```

Comment: Pra qual versão de mapa seria essa implementação, google maps v1 ou v2?

Comment: google maps v2...

Answer (score 1):

O código para ter ele adicionado no seu RelativeLayout seria assim:

```
<RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">


 <com.google.android.maps.MapView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map_view"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:enabled="true"
  android:apiKey="API-KEY-HERE" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Maaas, não é só adicionar isso, tem uma série de configurações para fazer...te recomendo ler a documentação da API do GMaps aqui: https://developers.google.com/maps/?hl=pt-br

E se quiser um tutorial de como fazer isso, pode seguir esse aqui:
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/android-google-maps-tutorial.html

ps: Para adicionar o GMaps na V2, pode seguir esse tutorial aqui:
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

Comment: Meu google maps já tá configurado googleConsole, já tenho chave e tudo que precisa.
O que preciso é adicionar dentro da minha classe que extends RelativeLayout sem uso de xml

Comment: E por que não usar o xml? E já leu a documentação deles?

Comment: Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo Template, que vai gerar telas a partir de JSON externo e preciso que minha classe seja programática e sem uso de xml

Comment: Dante, esse mapView não é da V1? Eu preciso na v2.

Comment: @IgorRonner, cara, achei um link aqui que pode ser super interessante pra você, dá uma olhada: http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/forum/threads/google-maps-android-v2-tutorial.24415/

Comment: @IgorRonner, atualizei minha resposta com um link bem explicado para a V2

Comment: Obrigado Dante, mas acabei fazendo um leve alteração para que eu pudesse carregar direto da minha main Activity e deu certo